# How to get value from a ModelAndView object in jsp Page?

Tags: spring-mvc

For eg:i use a method in controller class :

```
public ModelAndView fileupload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
```

Within that method i use

```
Map modelMap = new HashMap();
```

Then set the value like

```
modelMap.put(name,request.getParameter("uname"));
```

Then in modelView object I add the object like

```
modelView.addAllObjects(modelMap);
```

Then set the view like

```
modelView.setViewName("salu.jsp");
```

then returned modelView object.

It is displaying that jsp page but the value I print in jsp using the scriptlet like

```
<% String username=request.getAttribute("name"); 
   out.println("name is  "+username); %>.
```

But it is printing the value is null. Tell me how i can get thet Value.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming variable `name` value in your controller is `"name"`, just use `${name}` in your JSP.